# Laravel validator - Integrity constraint violation

Tags: validation, laravel

I have employees, which has (auto increment) unique id in database (pretty easy :) ) but I would like to check the uniqueness of other field which will be their employee_number  ..

While creating the new employee, it's pretty easy, because I just call:

```
$this->validate($request, [                
                           'employee_number' => 'required|unique:employees'
                           ]);
```

But how can I do this while editing existing employee? I would like to check (if the "edited" employee_number is unique for **OTHER** users ... it means that I need to rewrite this query to laravel validation form

```
employee_number NOT IN (SELECT employee_number 
                        FROM employees 
                        WHERE id = *edited_user_id*)
```

I tried to do this

```
$this->validate($request, [                
                           'employee_number' => 'required|unique:employees,id,'.$input['employee_id']
                           ]);
```

Imagine, there are records in a table "employees"

```
id |  name  | employee_number
-----------------------------
1  |  Peter |      0001
2  |  Paul  |      0002
3  |  Frank |      0003
```

When I try to change Frank's data -> it is ok .. even if i change his employee number to some unique one, it works ok ..

But when I insert existing one for Frank's account, i.e. 0001 it doesn't give me a proper error message (from validator) that employee number is already taken .. but instead of that, it redirects me to the error page

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

QueryException in Connection.php line 669:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0001' for key 'employees_employee_number' (SQL: *here comes the wrong sql query*)
```

Do you know how can I raise the proper error bar right above the form like when I try to insert new employee and try to insert the existing id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did one small mistake in `'required|unique:employees,id,'.$input['employee_id']`.
Now You are looking if your input `employee_number` is unique in `employees` table by `id` field.

Change that line to:
`'required|unique:employees,employee_number,'.$input['employee_id']` and You are good to go!

From Lavarel docs: `unique:table,column,except,idColumn`.

Comment: maaaaaaan, you're my lifesaver :) I owe you a beer !! +1 thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

If the Validator fails I collected the error message as shown

```
$rules = ['employee_number' => 

    'required|unique:employees,employee_number,'.$input['employee_id']]

    $validator = \Validator::make($data = \Input::all(), $rules);

            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return [
                    return [
                        "status" => "fail",
                        "errors" => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()
        ];
                ];
            }
```

Now collect the response from where you sent your request and in response you will get a associative array of error messages which you can use it according to your use.